# Can Bootstrap 4 handle a custom theme with light and dark mode triggered by toggle like Google's material design?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, frontend, bootstrap-4

I'm building a new application and I will modify some of the bootstrap UI elements by creating a custom theme including not just colors but modifications to UI elements and spacing. I'm new in front-end and I was wondering if bootstrap can handle light/dark theme AT The same time the same way material design does, for example:

[image]

[image]

Note: my back-end dev is using PHP and Ajax, we are not using react/angular/view and those new javascript frameworks to build the front-end.

Do we expect a lot of issues/glitches with this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Natively no.  But with a bit of JS/jQuery and a dark theme you can.
See [Guide to Dark Mode and Bootstrap](https://github.com/vinorodrigues/bootstrap-dark)

There is however issues (as you asked) in the case where you serve a primary light theme and a secondary dark theme AND the user prefers dark - when the page loads, it will load default (light) first and then swap to dark - creating a "flash".  Adapting the switch to Server Side (PHP) may fix the flash, but that requires significant work to swap the two themes.

In terms of UX philosophy however, if the browser supports the `prefers-color-scheme` media query then a toggle button should NOT be available as the browser or user OS will dictate the preference.

Answer (score 1):

If you just get your toggle to switch from one css file to another, you won't have any issues or glitches.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can use the jQuery element selector like (`#left, #right, #body`),
when the customer click on the special (main) button.

Then the background will be changed according to your theme (light/dark).